# Embarcadero c++ Cannot save text to .pdf

Tags: c++

I am using Embarcadero c++ and I am reading text from a file. I want to save that text to a .pdf document. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance... see my code below!

```
 memText ->Clear();
 AnsiString oneLine;
 AnsiString WordsFile = "ORCLE_daily_14aug12.txt";
 TStreamReader *stRead = new TStreamReader(WordsFile);

while (!stRead->EndOfStream)
{
    oneLine = stRead->ReadLine();
    memText->Lines->Add(oneLine);
}
stRead->Close();


AnsiString twoLine;
AnsiString WordsFile2 = "Daily_Report.pdf";
TStreamWriter *stWrite = new TStreamWriter(WordsFile2, false);

for (int ln = 0; ln <= memText->Lines->Count-1; ln++)
{
    oneLine = memText->Lines->Strings[ln];
    stWrite->WriteLine(oneLine);
}

memText->ScrollBars = ssVertical;
stWrite->Close();
```

Comment: You can't generate PDF by saving text with a "pdf" extension. You're going to need a PDF library.

Comment: Little sidenote: Why do you use Embarcadero? If you are not bound to interoperability with Delphi or the VCL, there are far better solutions.